# Chamadas de Sistema no Android

Tags: android, linux, sistema-operacional

Eu estou criando um comparativo entre as chamadas de sistema entre o Linux e o Android. No Linux eu consigo criar uns códigos e já encontrei algumas tabelas que demonstram as chamadas de sistema nele, mas no Andorid, eu não encontro nada.
Alguém sabem como se faz chamadas de sistema, e onde eu posso ver a questão do desempenho delas? Ou até mesmo, fornecer um material que demonstre algo sobre as chamadas de sistema no Android.

Answer (score 2):

Dê uma olhada nesses links:

- http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/
- http://shadowwhowalks.blogspot.it/2013/01/android-hacking-hooking-system.html
- http://www.opersys.com/blog/android-system-calls

Espero poder ter ajudado!
Boa sorte!

Comment: Alguns links desses eu já tinha visto, mas tem um que eu não tinha visto ainda que já ajudou bastante. Obrigado!

Comment: Disponha.. Boa sorte!